# Change property value and create new instance

Tags: arrays, swift, object, instance

I have a class that looks something like this and I need to set a default color of the tshirt *(ex. white)* and when the user choose another color form the array *(ex. red)* create a **new tshirt** with the property color filled with just the color selected *(red)*. How can I do that??

```
class Tshirt {
    var color: [String]
    var size: Int
    var price: Int

    init(color: [String], size: Int, price: Int) {
        self.color = color
        self.size = size
        self.price = price   
}
```

I'm sorry if this sounds stupid but I'm new to object oriented programming.

Comment: How is this SwiftUI? — Also: why would a color be an array, and why would it be an array of String?

Comment: @matt Ops I added SwiftUI by mistake. Color should contain the list of selectable colors.

Comment: So you are saying it doesn't matter that they are strings. — Ok but if `color` is an array of _possible_ colors, then you have no property that stands for the _actual_ color. You seem to be confused between a t-shirt and an offer of _possible_ t-shirts.

Comment: I don't know if it's possible but the first t-shirt should cotain all the possible colors.
After the selection by the user I need to create a brand new t-shirt where color is, for example, red. 
Do I need two different classes? (as I said, I'm a begginer in this field)

Answer (score 0):

Why would you want to create a new Tshirt when a color is picked rather than just changing the value for that Tshits's color? If there are a few colors to pick from you could create an enum for color and set the default color when the object is created to white.

```
class Tshirt {
    var color: Color = .white
    var size: Int
    var price: Int
    
    enum Color {
        case white, black, blue, green, red //etc...
    }

    init(size: Int, price: Int) {
        self.size = size
        self.price = price
    }
}
let yourShirt = Tshirt(size: 8, price: 8)
```

and `yourShirt` will have a color property of `.white`. Then when the user picks the desired color just change the color of the shirt.

```
yourShirt.color = .red
print(yourShirt.color)
//Prints "red"
```

If you truly want to instantiate a new object with a user defined color, or provide the option to instantiate a Tshirt object with a specified color you can change your initializer to have a default value to give you the option:

```
init(size: Int, price: Int, color: Color = .white) {
    self.size = size
    self.price = price
    self.color = color
}
```